# while doing join in pig "OR" condition will work or not?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to achieve the below SQL statement in PIG SCRIPT

Table1 a,b,c,d columns
Table2 w,x,y,z columns

```
Select t.a,t.b,t.c,t.d from Table1 t
Join Table2 tab on (t.a=tab.w or t.b=tab.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using two joins and union.Load the two datasets into relations A and B.Create a new relation C by joining on first condition t.a=tab.w.Create another new relation D by joining on second condition t.b=tab.x.UNION C AND D.Assuming all datatypes as int.

```
A = LOAD 'data1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (a:int,b:int,c:int,d:int);
B = LOAD 'data2.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (w:int,x:int,y:int,z:int);
C = JOIN A BY A.a,B BY B.w;
D = JOIN A BY A.b,B BY B.x;
E = UNION C,D;
DUMP E;
```